# Recursion: Nested dictionaries to XML(HTML)

Tags: python, xml, recursion

I'm trying to figure out the logic for a bit of code I'm working on. I have a dictionary of dictionaries. Basically, I'm taking a list of files and creating a web form from it.

I'm well aware that I need to use a recursive function, but the recursion bit is throwing my mind in a million directions and I can't figure out the logic required to make this work.

My dictionary of dictionaries...

```
{'Desktop': {'bar': {'buz': '/home/michael/t/Desktop/bar/buz',
                     'fuz': '/home/michael/t/Desktop/bar/fuz'},
             'foo': {'buz': '/home/michael/t/Desktop/foo/buz',
                     'fuz': '/home/michael/t/Desktop/foo/fuz'}},
 'Documents': {'bar': {'buz': '/home/michael/t/Documents/bar/buz',
                       'fuz': '/home/michael/t/Documents/bar/fuz'},
               'foo': {'buz': '/home/michael/t/Documents/foo/buz',
                       'fuz': '/home/michael/t/Documents/foo/fuz'},
               'good title': '/home/michael/t/Documents/good title'},
 'test.py': '/home/michael/t/test.py'}
```

I need that dictionary turned into this...

```
<ul id="master">
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="Desktop"><label for="Desktop">Desktop</label>
    <ul>
      <li><input type="checkbox" id="Desktop/bar"><label for="Desktop/bar">bar</label>
        <ul>
          <li><input type="checkbox" id="/home/michael/t/Desktop/bar/buz"><label for="/home/michael/t/Desktop/bar/buz">buz</label></li>
          <li><input type="checkbox" id="/home/michael/t/Desktop/bar/fuz"><label for="/home/michael/t/Desktop/bar/fuz">fuz</label></li>
        <ul>
      </li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" id="Desktop/bar"><label for="Desktop/foo">bar</label>
        <ul>
          <li><input type="checkbox" id="/home/michael/t/Desktop/foo/buz"><label for="/home/michael/t/Desktop/foo/buz">buz</label></li>
          <li><input type="checkbox" id="/home/michael/t/Desktop/foo/fuz"><label for="/home/michael/t/Desktop/foo/fuz">fuz</label></li>
        <ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="Documents"><label for="Documents">Desktop</label>
    <ul>
      <li><input type="checkbox" id="Documents/bar"><label for="Documents/bar">bar</label>
        <ul>
          <li><input type="checkbox" id="/home/michael/t/Documents/bar/buz"><label for="/home/michael/t/Documents/bar/buz">buz</label></li>
          <li><input type="checkbox" id="/home/michael/t/Documents/bar/fuz"><label for="/home/michael/t/Documents/bar/fuz">fuz</label></li>
        <ul>
      </li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" id="Documents/bar"><label for="Documents/foo">bar</label>
        <ul>
          <li><input type="checkbox" id="/home/michael/t/Documents/foo/buz"><label for="/home/michael/t/Documents/foo/buz">buz</label></li>
          <li><input type="checkbox" id="/home/michael/t/Documents/foo/fuz"><label for="/home/michael/t/Documents/foo/fuz">fuz</label></li>
        <ul>
      </li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" id="/home/michael/t/Documents/good title"><label for="/home/michael/t/Documents/good title">good title</label></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="/home/michael/t/test.py"><label for="/home/michael/t/test.py">test.py</label></li>
</ul>
```

Recursion is definitely a puzzle to me and this one is (to me) a rather advanced puzzle.

My best sad attempt so far...

```
def print_form(dictionary, root):
    '''
    Remove the root of the dictionary and then build the form.
    '''
    r = root.split('/')
    listing = dictionary[r[0]][r[1]][r[2]][r[3]]
    return '<ul id="master">{}</ul>'.format(build_xml('', listing))


def build_xml(group, listing):
    for k, v in listing.iteritems():
        if type(v) == dict:
            return '<ul><li><input type="checkbox" id="{0}"><label for="{0}">{1}</label></li>{2}</ul>'.format(group + '/' + k, k, build_xml(group + '/' + k, v))
        elif type(v) == str:
            return '<li><input type="checkbox" id="{0}"><label for="{0}">{1}</label></li>'.format(v, k)
```

Comment: ... and what exactly have you tried so far?

Comment: @PeterVaro I think the problem is he doesn't know where to begin.

Comment: I've tried a lot of things, but they accurately reflect my lack of knowledge and skill. I left my attempts out because they're embarrassing and pathetic.

Comment: `I've tried a lot of things` <- show us, and we'll show you how to fix it

Comment: You might want to look into something that implements the ElementTree API, like [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) or [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/).

Comment: @MTeck FYI, I'm pretty sure you want to be using a [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) rather than a `dict` - or else you have no idea in what order elements at the same level of the hierarchy are going to be output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think (hope) this does the job:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
import os

def dict_to_xml(dict_, parent_node=None, parent_name=''):
    def node_for_value(name, value, parent_node, parent_name):
        """
        creates the <li><input><label>...</label></input></li> elements.
        returns the <li> element.
        """
        value= os.path.join(parent_name, value)
        node= ElementTree.SubElement(parent_node, 'li')
        child= ElementTree.SubElement(node, 'input')
        child.set('type', 'checkbox')
        child.set('id', value)
        child= ElementTree.SubElement(child, 'label')
        child.set('for', value)
        child.text= name
        return node

    # create an <ul> element to hold all child elements
    if parent_node is None:
        node= ElementTree.Element('ul')
        node.set('id', 'master')
    else:
        node= ElementTree.SubElement(parent_node, 'ul')

    # add the sub-elements
    for key,value in dict_.iteritems():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            child= node_for_value(key, key, node, parent_name)
            dict_to_xml(value, child, key)
        else:
            node_for_value(key, value, node, parent_name)
    return node
```

This returns an [`ElementTree.Element`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element), you can convert it to xml like so:

```
dict_to_xml(my_dict).tostring()
```

or, to get formatted xml (for debugging purposes):

```
element= dict_to_xml(my_dict)

from xml.dom import minidom

xml= ElementTree.tostring(element)
xml= minidom.parseString(xml)
xml= xml.toprettyxml(indent='  ')
```

Comment: That worked absolutely perfect! It seems like a lot more work than anything I could have come up with but also a whole lot more robust and flexible. I want to understand this... gonna take me a *lot* of staring.